# Use Variable after this

Tags: c#, wpf

How is it possible to use a var after "this."

i want to set the Background color of a TextBlock to Blue.

```
 Brush blue = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue); //Working Fine


//Click on the TextBlock (Working Fine) 
    private void MouseDown_TextBlock(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
    
        var stand = ((TextBlock)sender).Name; //Here i am getting the Name of the TextBlock (Working Fine)
        this.stand.Background = blue; //This is not working here
    }
```

Comment: It's *really* unclear to me what you're trying to do, and what error you're facing - please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to include *much* more detail (including the error message, for a start).

Comment: i try to use a variable after "this." instead of the Name of the TextBlock itself.

Comment: Please don't just add a single comment - rewrite the whole question. It needs a *lot* more clarity, with full examples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you need the name? Why not simply `((TextBlock)sender).Background = blue;`

Comment: i am calling this method by several TextBlocks, so i need the name of the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the control you receive as Sender in an event, just cast it to the appropriate class:

```
private void textBlock1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Get sender as TextBlock
    TextBlock standTextBlockFromSender = (TextBlock)sender;
    standTextBlockFromSender.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));
}
```

If you want to find the control by name, you can use the [`FindName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname) method.

```
private void textBlock1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Get name of sender 
    string stand = ((TextBlock)sender).Name;

    // Get TextBlock by name
    TextBlock standTextBlockFromName = (TextBlock)this.FindName(stand);

    standTextBlockFromName.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));
}
```